# cannot open connection in an r script that worked previously

Tags: r

I am having a "cannot open the connection" error in an R script. Below are the details:

```
> write.csv(table1.fiveReitWts,file="C:\\Users\\John Broussard\\Dropbox\\evtHandbookProject\\figuresTables\\figure3Data.csv")
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\John Broussard\Dropbox\evtHandbookProject\figuresTables\figure3Data.csv': No such file or directory
>
```

This is a new file being created, but the directory exists. I can see the directory, which contains other files.  I have used this code previously with success, but all of a sudden, I am unable to write a file to this directory.

What additional information can I provide to help you help me resolve this error?

Comment: BTW, I have not seen this error previously, hence, the perplexity.

Comment: Is your hard disk full?

Comment: @gung, I *think* the double backslashes (\\\) take care of the problem in Windows.

Comment: Two things come to mind: 1) a typo, please double check. Also, what do you get if you run `list.files("C:\\Users\\John Broussard\\Dropbox\\evtHandbookProject\\figuresTables")` or `setwd` in that dir? 2) file permissions: please check you have write-access to that dir.

Comment: Here's the result when running the list.files()

list.files("C:\\Users\\John Broussard\\Dropbox\\evtHandbookProject\\figuresTables")
character(0)

Comment: Even after I setwd to the directory, I get the same result:

setwd("C:/Users/Dr. John Broussard/Dropbox/evtHandbookProject/figuresTables")
> list.files("C:\\Users\\John Broussard\\Dropbox\\evtHandbookProject\\figuresTables")
character(0)

I don't understand what's going on.  I was writing files to the directory of interest only a week ago and made no changes to the code since.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use an escape character for the whitespace in your filepath. I would try to write the whole thing like this:

```
C:/Users/John\ Broussard/Dropbox/evtHandbookProject/figuresTables/figure3Data.csv
```

EDIT:

Since this was apparently not the source of the problem, maybe the file is opened in another process?
What if you copy the file and try to open the copy?

Comment: I can write files to folders that have whitespace in the filepath w/o escaping on my machine. I do it commonly & just tested it.

Comment: No you don't. I can confirm that a path with spaces will work fine on Windows as long as it is totally enclosed with `""`'s

Comment: okay, sorry, didn't know that this was possible in Win. My intuition as a Linux/Unix/MacOs user just told me that it wouldnt work.

Comment: No problem, @SebastianRaschka, happens to me all the time. You may want to delete this answer, though.